# iOS: Build XYZ.framework with multiple libraries (xyz.a)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, frameworks, static-libraries

i have build a XYZ.framework package for iOS with the folowing folder-structure:

*ls XYZ.framework*

```
XYZ -> Libraries/libxyz.a
Headers -> Home/Headers
Home -> SDKs/Current
Libraries -> Home/Libraries
SDKs
```

*ls XYZ.framework/SDKs*

```
4.2
Current -> 4.2
```

*ls XYZ.framework/SDKs/Current*

```
Headers
Libraries
```

It works fine with one .a library file.

But how to include more than one .a library file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0) iOS does not allow you to publish dynamic libs at this time (unless that's a recent change)

1) set up your framework's project to include the dependencies

2) add the depends to the build invocation (target dependencies) and link phase.

3) if your framework creates no objects (e.g. exports no symbols, or compiles no files), then you may need to add a dummy file with something such as an inline function (or the image's constructor/destructor).

4) then link to the static depends to produce the final image. this step should merge all images.

Comment: note that this doesn't account for the headers. if you want to publish headers with your framework, then add them as public headers in the framework project.

Comment: Ok, tank you for your answer. I don't build the libs with XCode. I wan't to make a .framework including the headers and libs i created bevore, so that somebody who want's to use the framework don't need to change anything in his projects settings. With add dependencies he must modify the projects header path and library path.

Comment: even if you don't build the libs with xcode, you can still invoke the build from a run script phase in xcode while following these steps. xcode just serves as a front end for other tools. so, you'll have to create a script to produce a framework, a plist, then look at the toolchain arguments xcode creates to get the build arguments correct. adding the headers to the project as public ultimately copies the headers into the framework (product) bundle. since this is tagged as iphone - i still don't see how you'll accomplish distributing a dynamic library. (cont)

Comment: there really is no way to avoid changing the search paths unless you write the headers to be relative to one of your client's search paths. adding a search path and linking to a static lib should be expected when targeting iOS and using a 3rd party lib, unless you are distributing Xcode projects (things change slightly then).

Comment: It is possible to create iOS frameworks, but not with Xcode. They behave a little differently. See http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1594